# Formula only recognizes one submission

Tags: google-sheets, formula

My goal is to make it so that the spreadsheet checks to see if the respective Web ID [in Column B](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T6TUzySQTLzjMni9ZyDWOFs6YnRqSwtzJ317ilJ0Y0Q/edit#gid=1408805184) has an Active LOA as determined in [Column I](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T6TUzySQTLzjMni9ZyDWOFs6YnRqSwtzJ317ilJ0Y0Q/edit#gid=1817696719). An Active LOA being defined as one with an end date that has NOT yet passed.

I've gotten the formulas to work with the first entry. But if that first entry's date has passed (marked as Expired) and the entry after that one hasn't passed (marked as Active LOA) then the formula breaks down. It's as if the formula works only once.

The formula that checks the respective Web ID's in Column B of the "Roster" tab against the Web ID in the "ScD LOA Responses" tab is in cell F9 of the "Roster" tab.

The formula that determines whether or not the date has passed/whether the person is still on LOA is found in column I of the respective row.

Comment: Here is a link to a video that should help explain things more clearly; https://streamable.com/v0m4jj

Comment: Can you share a copy of the spreadsheet? That will make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting wrong result on second row because you have `lock` the range on first row, change it as following should work properly:

```
=IF($F3:$F<TODAY(),"Expired","Active LOA")
```

You may try `arrayformula` also by only enter formula on `F3`:

```
=arrayformula(if($F3:$F="","",IF($F3:$F<today(),"expired","active")))
```

The issue for `Roaster` is not syn with the form submission is because `Vlookup` is limited to return `first occurence` unless you make so adjustment, here I will give a simple solution to always return the `latest result` for syn:

```
 =iferror(index(FILTER('SC LOA Response'!C$3:$I,'SC LOA Response'!C$3:C=B6),COUNTIF('SC LOA Response'!C$3:C,B6),7),"")
```

Since your roster is fixed number, you can copy the formula on every row, hope it solve your issue :)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, I'm getting the same results. If the first row says "Active LOA" then it'll say it on the "Roster", but if the second row says "Active LOA" and the first one says "Expired" then it won't show up as Active LOA on the Roster even though it should.

Comment: Is it because your spread sheet time zone affect the result? Go `file > Spreadsheet setting` and see my image above. if you data is fall on `6June`, maybe in other country still not pass the date for `today`. Try syn both time zone and `refresh`.

Comment: I see the confusion - it works there, the results are correct with the times. It's just not syncing correctly to the other tab called "Roster".

For example, when the first row is set to "Active LOA" - it syncs to the "Roster" tab as shown here: https://prnt.sc/14gsm6s

But when the first row is set to "Expired" and the second row is set to "Active LOA" - it doesn't sync to the main Roster tab, as shown here: https://prnt.sc/14gsumz

Comment: I think the problem come from conditional formatting, as it is grey out, you cannot edit the formula also

Comment: when the first row is set to "Active LOA" - it syncs to the "Roster" tab as shown here: prnt.sc/14gsm6s But when the first row is set to "Expired" and the second row is set to "Active LOA" - it doesn't sync to the main Roster tab, as shown here: prnt.sc/14gsumz

Comment: I saw the video already, let me take a look on the `roaster` formula for the issue

Comment: See my edited answer, I try to use `arrayformula`, however it return `#NA#`, I think it is because `filter` is part of the formula

Comment: It's not working - it's giving me a "Circular Dependency" error.

Comment: I have edited the formula to fit your sheet, please test it , thank you

Comment: I've tried that formula and it doesn't appear to be doing anything - I'm not sure if I'm putting it in the right place?

https://gyazo.com/976d63156239df9303b03f39e41f446c

Comment: The formula is supposed to be used in your `Roaster Col F`, the reason for both side are not in syn because of the `Vlookup` formula only return `first occurence`,

Comment: That makes sense - is there a reason when I paste the formula in each cell for Column F, it's just displaying as a white background?
https://gyazo.com/6fa39c5a5efa439c2cfc36d700aaeb4c

Comment: You should use `paste formula only` to prevent overwrite the existing format, and try relink the `data range` for the `SC LOA Response` as I am typing based on your `sheetname`

Comment: I've re-linked the data to the correct sheet, this link has edit access maybe it might be easier for you to diagnose that way;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T6TUzySQTLzjMni9ZyDWOFs6YnRqSwtzJ317ilJ0Y0Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, I saw some problem no sure why return `2` is blank, let me try it later, will get back to you. In my own sheet it is working

Comment: No problem! Thanks for going out of your way to assist with this problem!

Comment: OK, it is settle already, I have changed you `conditional formatting ` when it is `expired` to white text font, adjust if you need because it is so dark that it cannot be see, accept if helping :)

Comment: It works now - thanks for the assistance!